# Getting Applet Parameters from Slick2D Game

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl, slick2d

In a Slick2D game, how can I access parameters passed to the `AppletGameContainer`?

I've got a Slick2D game that I'd like to run both as an applet, and as a standalone application.

When the game is running as an applet, I'd like to access some information passed to it. I was thinking maybe I could do an `instanceof` check of the `GameContainer` in `StateBasedGame#initGameStates`, but `AppletGameContainer` does not inherit from `GameContainer`.

Is there a feature of the Slick2D framework that allows for easy access to applet parameters, or better still, some layer of abstraction that will allow access to applet parameters or command-line arguments, without my game having to know which container it was started by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppletGameContainer` doesn't share the same heritage, but instead defines a public inner class, the rather ambiguously-named `Container`. It is an instance of *this* that gets passed to the `StateBasedGame` implementation.

Hence the check should have been:

```
container instanceof AppletGameContainer.Container
```

...and the code to acquire the parameters:

```
((AppletGameContainer.Container) container).getParameter("paramKey");
```